# what happen when flock processed?

Tags: php, http, synchronization

I need help in this scenario,

I need to write in the file for some reason during the handling of request, So I used flock to be sure there is just one request is writing in the file in the same time.

My questions is what happen when a request call flock during locked by other request. is it wait until released or just return false and do not open the file?

Comment: You could test this yourself with like 3 lines of code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)

> By default, this function will block until the requested lock is acquired

Just be sure to use the right lock (see doc)

- LOCK_SH to acquire a shared lock (reader).
- LOCK_EX to acquire an exclusive lock (writer).

basically a *writer* waits for an exclusive lock, meaning it waits for all readers or the current writer to release the(ir) lock(s). While *readers* may be more than one to read the file.

and, to release the lock

- LOCK_UN to release a lock (shared or exclusive).